# Change HTML on mobile/tablet device

Tags: html, button, media-queries

I have button 1 and button 2. I have to show button 1 if I am in a computer screen, instead, I have to show button 2 if I'm in mobile/tablet devices.
So, I want that something that can change the visible html in my page.
There is something like mediaquery for html? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, media-queries could be used to get the result you want. But you use them in your css-style sheets.

Something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  .btn-mobile-visible {
      visibility: visible;
  };

  .btn-desktop-visible {
      visibility: hidden;
  };    
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) {
  .btn-mobile-visible {
      visibility: hidden;
  };

  .btn-desktop-visible {
      visibility: visible;
  };   
}
```

And then in your html you just add the css-classes on you buttons:

```
<button class="btn-desktop-visible">Visible in desktop</button>
<button class="btn-mobile-visible">Visible in mobile</button>
```

Unwanted side effects could be if the user changes the size of his/hers browser window - that would probably make things a little messy :)

Comment: it's a good solution, but is it possible to select ALL mobile/tablet devices? I don't have defined resolution sizes.

Comment: Media queries work with max/min widths/heights and apply the specified css classes for those widths/heights. It doesn't look at anything like "devices" I'm afraid.
If you want to have a solution based on devices, you should look at some javascript library or something like http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ and then use jQuery or something to hide/show buttons or other elements. That solution will pretty fast get quite messy though :)

Comment: I did @media screen and (max-device-width: 600px){ } and If I am in portrait, it works, the but is hidden, if I switch in landscape, the button is hidden, but if I switch again in portrait, the button appear o.o how is it possible??

Comment: You could try to add a meta tag that disables zooming and sets the scale and viewport for the screen of the device.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Yay! I'm glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the visibility of your buttons with css media queries. Or use a library like [head.js](http://headjs.com/) to determine what kind of browser you are on and then insert the correct button via javascript.