# How to change the buttons display order from desktop to mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have buttons like below:

```
<button>cancel</button>
<button>submit</button>
```

The `cancel` button is on the left side and submit is on the right side. When it comes to mobile view I have to display `submit` on top and `cancel` on the bottom. How can I do this?

Here is my example: http://plnkr.co/edit/BpTrv6aI5xDCBNddUPj1?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26710447/894111

Answer (score 2):

You can look at using a media query to change the display of the buttons when you hit a certain threshold:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    button {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Displaying the buttons as `block` will show them one on top of another.

Comment: I tried to add this but it doesn't work for me. Can you please update this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BpTrv6aI5xDCBNddUPj1?p=preview

Comment: It's working when I try.  You just need to shrink down your screen to hit the width threshold specified in the media query (`max-width: 480px`).  You can tweak that max-width value as you see fit.

Comment: So, in mobile view your seeing "submit" button on top and "cancel" on bottom right?

Comment: I'm simulating a mobile view by shrinking my result part of the screen.  Update the `max-width` value if it's not working quite right for you.

Comment: I am trying to get "submit" on top and "cancel" on bottom in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the buttons and float them on desktop, then give them full width on mobile:

```
<button class="pull-right">submit</button>
<button class="pull-left">cancel</button>
```

And this CSS should be on desktop:

```
.pull-right {
    float:right;
}

.pull-left {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solutions to change display order of buttons from mobile to desktop

```
<http://plnkr.co/edit/JQS9vQRIeHgLC5EtCkDh?p=preview>
```